# sort by column from pivot table

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables,

```
auctions
+----+----------+
| ID | NAME     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Lelang 1 |
+----+----------+
| 2  | Lelang 2 |
+----+----------+
| 3  | Lelang 3 |
+----+----------+

levels
+----+---------+
| ID | NAME    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Level 1 |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Level 2 |
+----+---------+
| 3  | Level 3 |
+----+---------+

auction_level
+----+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| ID | AUCT_ID | LEVEL_ID | DATE_START | DATE_END   |
+----+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1        | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-10 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 1       | 2        | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-31 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 2       | 1        | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-15 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to select all entries of `auctions` table and sort by `DATE_START` of `Level 1` on table `auction_level`. honestly I have no idea how to make  the desired query, so there is no any queries that I have created yet.

Comment: You should read about _joins_ between tables.  You will learn more this way than just being given an answer here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, already solved by ordinary join.. I was overthinking. thanks.

Comment: @DarielPratama please either close or answer yourself